# Mockito how to match String[][] argument?

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock

My mock object has this method I want to verify being called:

```
void postResource(String url, int x, String[][] headers)
```

How do I use the `any()` methods to verify if `postResource` was called with any `headers` parameter?

```
http = mock(Http.class);
verify(http, never()).postResource(anyString, anyInt(), ?)
```

Even better, is there a way to just verify a method with any combination of arguments? Something like

```
verify(http, never()).postResource(anyArguments)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Mockito.any(String[][].class)
```